# An issue with the distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions

I am reading a book about Boltzmann equation, here is a quotation:

> For a gas of $N$ particles, the number of particles having velocities in the  $x$ direction between $c_x$ and $c_x + \mathrm dc_x$ is $Nf(c_x)\mathrm dc_x$. The function $f(c_x)$ is the fraction
>   of the particles having velocities in the interval $c_x$ and $c_x + \mathrm dc_x$; in the x-direction.

I am really confused, why the number of particles having velocities in $c_x$ and $c_x+\mathrm dc_x$ is given by $Nf(c_x)\mathrm dc_x$? why do we multiply by $\mathrm dc_x$?

Can you explain please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly a first order approximation for the distribution of velocities. Strictly speaking, the fraction of particles with velocities in the interval is $\int_{c_x}^{c_x+dc_x}f(c)dc$. But if $dc_x$ is small and $f$ is roughly continuous, then one can assume that $f$ is constant on the interval to obtain
$$\int_{c_x}^{c_x+dc_x}f(c)dc\approx\int_{c_x}^{c_x+dc_x}f(c_x)dc=f(c_x)dc_x.$$ Then multiply by $N$ to turn this fraction into a quantity of particles.

If this seems imprecise, it's because you're reading a book about physics and not math!

Comment: But the fraction of particles (if it is the average) then it will be $f(c_x)=\dfrac{\int_{c_x}^{c_x+dc_x}f(c)dc}{\int_{c_x}^{c_x+dc_x}dc}$

Comment: @Syntax_ErrorX00 I'm having trouble reading that equation. Have you studied probability density functions?

Comment: but the book states that the fraction of particles is $f(c_x)$ not $f(c_x)dc_x$

Comment: They're not explaining their notation very precisely. You can see that $f(c)$ does not give the fraction itself since then it wouldn't depend on the choice of $dc_x$. This is the confusion that arises when authors try to use PDFs but avoid any mention of calculus.

Comment: what do you mean by PDF? does it mean the PDF file?

Comment: Sorry, I mean probability density function, which is what the authors probably intend with $f$.

Comment: anyway, that was really a great answer, thank you again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41676/discussion-between-stan-corey-carter-and-syntax-errorx00).